# Confused about basic multiple-table relation & access using Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a few data models (tables) which are associated with each other. If a model has a related field pointing to another model, no problem, i can access that easy in the templates but how do I make calls that have reverse-only relation?

Example:

`Company` may have any number of `Location` and each Location may have any number of `Contact`.

So the `Company` table mentions neither the Location or Contact, but `Location` has a fk to Company. and `Contact` has a fk to Location.

In the template, I'd like to display Companies that match certain criteria. With them, I'd like their locations and their locations contacts to also display.

My thought is, maybe I make the `Company` query first, then make another for `Location` (and `Contact`) and some how inject them into the same dict but that sounds awfully confusing to me and this, im sure, is a common pattern.

Any tips?

Comment: "relation" is an ambiguous term with ORM topics; "relation" is the technical term for a table or query result.  References are referred to in the django documentation as "relation *ships*", and you should try to use that term and not "relation" when you are talking about how rows(instances) in one table(model) relate to rows in other tables.

Comment: duly noted. Thanks for letting me know. Knowing the correct terminology counts for most of my struggle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a `ForeignKey` field on one model, the target model automatically gets a attribute called `<referring_model>_set` - so in your example, each `Company` instance has a `location_set` attribute, and each `Location` has a `contact_set` attribute. These attributes actually refer to `Manager` instances, similar to `Company.objects`, that return only objects related to the current instance.

You can use these backwards references to iterate through the related objects in your templates, e.g.:

```
<ul>
{% for location in company.location_set %}
    <li>
        <em>{{ location.name }}</em>
        <ul>
        {% for contact in location.contact_set %}
            <li>{{ contact.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can read more about this kind of backwards relationship [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me. After realizing what terminology to look for, I see there are many questions here, all asking the same thing. Sorry to repost but thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: Well, as you noted above, if you knew the terminology already, you probably wouldn't have to ask the question :). That's why a human-powered resource like SO has an advantage over Google.